# configure two mongodb instances in Spring MVC appcontext.xml file?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data-mongodb

How to configured mongo cluster details (it uses two servers) in Spring MVC applicationContext.xml?

```
<mongo id="mongo" host="${mongo.db.host}" port="${mongo.db.port}"/>
```

database.properties

```
mongo.db.host=server1
mongo.db.port=27017
```

My mongodb is clustered database shared load balancing between two server (`server1 and server2`)? What configuration I need to use so that my application points to both databases? Please help provide pointers/answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by cluster you mean a shard environment, then you connect to `mongos`. In that case you give the host and port of the `mongos` instance you are connecting to, but the XML configuration should be the same.

If however you mean a replica set, your configuration should look like:

`<mongo id="mongo" replica-set="${mongo.db.replica-set}" />`

database.properties

`mongo.db.replica-set=server1:27017,server2:27017`

Replace `server1` and `server2` with real server names. The principal is a list of `host:port` entries separated by commas.